# How to flush buffer to file in linux when program is running?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

You know, we can use `setbuf -e0 -o0 <cmd>` to run program without buffer. Now, program has started without 'stdbuf', it write log to file. I can't find the log immediately due to buffer. Is there a certain `command` that can actively flush the buffer to the file so that I can see `buffer` when I open the file.

Comment: I don't think that a general mechanism for this can exist. After all, we don't know for certain (from the outside) how the buffering of some program is actually implemented. Of course the author of a program can invent such a mechanism for his program.

Comment: The'buffer' here I can clearly specify that it is the default buffer of the system(Centos7/8).

Comment: I don't think that the system "has a default buffer". Most likely you want to say that the process is using the C library function defined in `stdio.h` for this purpose?

Comment: But if you are referring to the internal cache of the file system, you can flush this using the `sync` command. Still, I don't see how this would cause an application which is using buffered I/O flush their buffer too. Some programs are designed so that when they receive a SIGHUP or SIGUSR1, they also flush the buffer. This is something you could try.

Comment: ```stdbuf``` can influence program so that i think it's system level behavior.

Comment: `stdbuf` sets up the standard streams for this program **before** it is started, After this, buffering is left to the program. If this were not the case, you could not change the buffering policy from inside your program.

Comment: What I need is an afterthought. As for what it is related to, I don’t care.  Like ```gdb -p <pid>```. When i forgot to add ```stdbuf``` prefix to running program ,  i can have a remedy to achieve the same effect.